# Optimizing Several Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I will try to add a class using jQuery.

```
var tit = ('.tit a');
txt_animal = ['pig','horse','rabbit','cat','monkey'];
txt_fruit = ['melon','apple','kiwi','orange'];
txt_hobby = ['movie','ski','swim','dance','internet','baseball'];

$(txt_animal).each(function(i,v){
    $(tit + ':contains("'+ v +'")').addClass('tag tag_animal');
}
$(txt_fruit).each(function(i,v){
    $(tit + ':contains("'+ v +'")').addClass('tag tag_fruit');
}
$(txt_hobby).each(function(i,v){
    $(tit + ':contains("'+ v +'")').addClass('tag tag_hobby');
}
```

It works fine. But i think a better way than this.
How to optimize javascript for the best performance?

Comment: don't optimize for performance unless it's necessary. do you really have performance problems with this?

Comment: are txt_animal and it's siblings supposed to be globals?

Comment: are you missing a dollar sign in line 1?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen I am a javascript newbie. Just looking for a better way.

Comment: answer my questions. the best way is not always the way with the best performance. it's okay you're a newbie, just try to learn. what made you think performance was your #1 priority?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen I don't understand fully that code. However, 'each' to repeat that my code is stupid I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should avoid both repeated (and expensive) DOM queries *and* repeated iterations through the possible matches, by using a regular expression for each class of tag.

```
var txt = {
  animal: /(pig|horse|rabbit|cat|monkey)/i,
  fruit: /(melon|apple|kiwi|orange)/i,
  hobby: /(movie|ski|swim|dance|internet|baseball)/i
};

$('.tit a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);       // saves three calls to `$(this)`
    var t = $this.text();      // get the text contents of the link

    for (var tag in txt) {     // for each key word
       if (txt[tag].test(t)) { // test the text against the regexp
           $this.addClass('tag').addClass('tag_' + tag);
       }
    }
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/DFcFH/1/

Answer (score 1):

Optimize for DRY instead.

```
var tit = ('.tit a');
var txt = {
  "animal": ['pig','horse','rabbit','cat','monkey'],
  "fruit": ['melon','apple','kiwi','orange'],
  "hobby": ['movie','ski','swim','dance','internet','baseball']
};

for (var cat in txt) {
  $(txt[cat]).each(function(i,v){
    $(tit + ':contains("'+ v +'")').addClass('tag tag_' + cat);
  });
}
```

Comment: Did you actually test this code?  Not only does it contain unnecessary repetition itself, it's also broken.